# How to create a array of arrays (or matrix) from a txt file data (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.txt', 'utf8',(err,data)=>{
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

I have this code I found on a youtube tutorial, it just reads the data from the text file, now I have this:

```
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
```

Now, in order to work with that data I have to make it look like this:

```
[[1,0,1,0,1],
 [1,0,1,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1]];
```

Only restriction is that I can´t use loops in this assigment (while & for loops), every function that is build in javascript is allowed, I can also use the Underscore library (https://underscorejs.org/)

I am just starting with Javascript, please let me know if there is some useful function or something that I can do to make it, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are just starting with JavaScript then first build a working solution in any way you can and only then start thinking how to comply with your specific limitations.  Simple rule: Learn to walk before attempting to run.

Comment: FYI I'm pretty sure Underscore contains loops in some form so that requirement seems to be completely arbitrary.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but I can´t use while() or for(), but I can use the function forEach() or other functions that have internal loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.trim()` whitespace from both ends of string:

   ```
   txt.trim()
   ```
2. `.split()` at each line break `\n`:

   ```
   txt.trim().split(/\n/)
   // ["1 0 1 0 1", "1 0 1 0 1", "0 0 0 0 1", "1 0 1 0 0", "1 0 0 0 1"]
   ```
3. `.map()` to each string in array and `.split()` at each `\s`:

   ```
   txt.trim().split(/\n/).map(row => row.split(/\s/))
   // See example for output
   ```
4. `.map()` to each sub-array then `.map()` to convert string into a real number:

   ```
   lines.map(row => row.map(bit => +bit));
   // See example for output
   ```

```js
// Utility function
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

const txt = `
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1`;

// Result is an array of string arrays
const lines = txt.trim().split(/\n/).map(row => row.split(/\s/));
log(lines);

// Convert the strings into real numbers
const bits = lines.map(row => row.map(bit => +bit));
log(bits);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
It works, but for some reason it deletes the last number of the last array, not sure why but for the moment is really usefull

Comment: solved by adding "lines[lines.length-1].push("");" before the bits step